# Independent Events or Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory

First recall the following definition of independent random variables.

> Let $(X_t)_{t \in \mathcal T}$ be a set of random variables, where $\mathcal T$ is an arbitrary index set. Then $(X_t)$ is called independent if for any ***finite*** subset $\mathcal I \subset \mathcal T$, the finite set $(X_i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$ is independent in the usual sense.

My question here is why do we need to emphasize the term ***finite*** in the above definition, please? **Why don't we require that for any subset $\mathcal I \subset \mathcal T$, finite or countable or even arbitrary, the set $(X_i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$ is independent, please?** Thank you!

Comment: "if for any finite subset blah blah blah" can reasonably be construed as "if there is any finite subset for which blah blah blah".  Or it can be construed as "if it is the case that for any finite subset, no matter which one, blah blah blah".  The ambiguity vanishes if you change "any" to "every".  That's what I would do here.

Comment: I guess, independence was first defined only for finite (two) random variables. Then, this is the follow-up.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Why don't we require that for any subset $\mathcal I \subset \mathcal T$, finite or countable or even arbitrary, the set $(X_i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$ is independent, please?

Comment: @Berci That is a good point. However, why is finiteness necessary for the definition of independence in the first place, please?

Comment: @20824 : Another reason is that it is awkward to work with CDFs like $F(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ because they tend to be inconveniently zero.  For example, if $\{X_1, X_2, \ldots\}$ are i.i.d. Gaussian, then for any finite $N$ we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} Pr[X_1\leq x, X_2 \leq x, \ldots, X_N\leq x] = 1$ but $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} Pr[X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x, \ldots] =0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is asking why the definition for a given infinite collection of random variables to be independent does not rely on the condition that some infinite collections of random variables are independent. If it did, one would have a *logical loop*, not a definition.